# Text Fields, Labels and Buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am having some difficulty understanding GUIs and why my program won't run properly. Is it because I have to extend to a JFrame class? Here is a code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Lab_10
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final double EARTHQUAKE_RATE= 8.0;

        final int FRAME_WIDTH= 300;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT= 200;
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle("Richter Scale");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(rictherfield);
        panel.add(rictherlabel);
        add(panel);

        JLabel rictherlabel = new JLabel ("Ricther: ");

        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
        JTextField rictherField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        richterField.setText("" + EARTHQUAKE_RATE);

        JButton button = new JButton("Enter");

        ActionListner listner = new AddLabelListener();
        button.addActionListner(listner);

        class AddLabelListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                label.setText("Most structures fall");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a lot of errors stating that the program cannot find the symbols for my ActionListeners etc.

Errors are:

```
  _10.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
    import java.awt.event.ActionListner;
                         ^
      symbol:   class ActionListner
      location: package java.awt.event
    Lab_10.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    ^
      symbol:   variable frame
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    frame.setTitle("Richter Scale");
    ^
      symbol:   variable frame
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ^
      symbol:   variable frame
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    ^
      symbol:   variable frame
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    panel.add(button);
              ^
      symbol:   variable button
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    panel.add(rictherfield);
              ^
      symbol:   variable rictherfield
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
    panel.add(rictherlabel);
              ^
      symbol:   variable rictherlabel
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    add(panel);
    ^
      symbol:   method add(JPanel)
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    richterField.setText("" + EARTHQUAKE_RATE);
    ^
      symbol:   variable richterField
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    ActionListner listner = new AddLabelListener();
    ^
      symbol:   class ActionListner
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    ActionListner listner = new AddLabelListener();
                                ^
      symbol:   class AddLabelListener
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    class AddLabelListener implements ActionListener
                                      ^
      symbol:   class ActionListener
      location: class Lab_10
    Lab_10.java:53: error: local variable label is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
    label.setText("Most structures fall");
```

Comment: Paste specific errors you're getting please.

Comment: I am sorry these are my errors

Comment: @SameerSawla, no you should not be extending JFrame, especially just bo make compile errors go away. You extend a class when you add functionality to the class.

Comment: No they are still there.

Comment: `import java.awt.event.ActionListner;` - you have a typo. You are missing an "e" in "Listener".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Yup I did that . That was my frnd who did that. Sorry fr inconvenience guys. Glad you appreciated the answer. Hope one day will earn reputation as yours.

Answer (score 2):

Issue 1 :

```
 frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
 frame.setTitle("Richter Scale");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setVisible(true); 

 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

You are trying to use an object that is not yet created. frame object is created at a later point in time. It should be as below :

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
 frame.setTitle("Richter Scale");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setVisible(true);
```

Issue 2:

Same issue further down the code.
Brother, first you need to declare an object, then only you can use it and implement functions on it. If you are not declaring the object first, how would compiler parse it and treat it as a valid variable.

```
 panel.add(button);
 panel.add(label);
 panel.add(rictherfield);
 panel.add(rictherlabel);
 add(panel);

 JLabel rictherlabel = new JLabel ("Ricther: ");

 final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
 JTextField rictherField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
 richterField.setText("" + EARTHQUAKE_RATE);


 JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
```

'button', 'richterlabel' & 'richterField' are used before their declaration. As compiler does not know what dese variables mean at the time of execution, it throws up saying cannot find symbol.

First declare them and then use them. Hope you got the point.

Issue 3:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListner;
```

ActionListner is not a class in the Event package. It should be :

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

Looking for other issues, Meanwhile start working on this.

Answer (score 2):

Wow... OK, first, `ActionListener` is spelled incorrectly as "`ActionListner`." Look very closely at the spelling of those words. Simple typographical errors generate syntax errors.

The rest of your problems boil down to this very simple caveat: **order matters**. Your order should be as follows:

1) declare and create objects;
2) declare and create all dependent objects;
3) configure objects;
4) manipulate objects.

That means that your code:

```
frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
frame.setTitle("Richter Scale");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
```

Won't work because you're trying to mess with a frame that hasn't yet been created. Create it first, like so:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
frame.setTitle("Richter Scale");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Same holds true for your label and your button.

```
JLabel rictherlabel = new JLabel ("Ricther: ");
```

needs to come before

```
panel.add(label);
```