# Trouble with Text Fields and GUI

Tags: java, swing

Errors

```
Lab_10.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
richterLabel = new JLabel("Richter");
^
  symbol:   variable richterLabel
  location: class Lab_10

Lab_10.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
label.setText("Most structures fall");
^
  symbol:   variable label
  location: class Lab_10.AddLabelListener

Lab_10.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
ActionListner listner = new AddLabelListener();
^
  symbol:   class ActionListner
  location: class Lab_10

Lab_10.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
panel = new JPanel();
^
  symbol:   variable panel
  location: class Lab_10

Lab_10.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
panel.add(richterLabel);
          ^
  symbol:   variable richterLabel
  location: class Lab_10

Lab_10.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
panel.add(richterLabel);
^
  symbol:   variable panel
  location: class Lab_10

Lab_10.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
panel.add(eField);
^
  symbol:   variable panel
  location: class Lab_10

Lab_10.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
panel.add(button);
^
  symbol:   variable panel
  location: class Lab_10

Lab_10.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
panel.add(earthLabel);
^
  symbol:   variable panel
  location: class Lab_10

Lab_10.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
add(panel);
    ^
  symbol:   variable panel
  location: class Lab_10
10 errors
```

The code...

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;

 public class Lab_10 extends JFrame
 {

 private final double EARTHQUAKE_RATE= 8.0;
 private final int FRAME_WIDTH= 300;
 private final int FRAME_HEIGHT= 200;

 private JLabel rictherLabel;
 private JTextField eField;
 private JButton button;
 private JLabel earthLabel;

 public Lab_10()
 {
 earthLabel = new JLabel("Most structures fall");

 makeTextField();
 makeButton();
 makePanel();
 setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
 }

 private void makeTextField()
  {
 richterLabel = new JLabel("Richter");

 final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
 eField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
 eField.setText("" + EARTHQUAKE_RATE);
 }


 class AddLabelListener implements ActionListener
 {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
 {
 label.setText("Most structures fall");
 }
 }

 private void makeButton()
 {
 button = new JButton("Enter");

 ActionListener listener = new AddLabelListener();
 button.addActionListener(listener);
 }

 private void makePanel()
  {
 panel = new JPanel();
 panel.add(richterLabel);
 panel.add(eField);
 panel.add(button);
 panel.add(earthLabel);
 add(panel);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can anybody tell me why I am getting these errors

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: I retract it. His spelling is off. It's a careless spelling error. Lord. And he's still spelling "ActionListner" wrong -- so yes, he is still not learning from his previous answers.

Comment: Well I thought I declared it by adding in private JLabel earthLabel etc. and yeah @HovercraftFullOfEels I am a beginner at this but I guess that does not matter right.... so yeah thanks for your honesty either way.

Comment: Ok I am sorry about that I changed the spelling errors please explain to me about declaring my variables. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Why are you reposting this question? You already got a lot of help when you posted it the [first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341366/text-fields-labels-and-buttons/20341508#20341508).

Comment: @MarsAtomic: I think that it's the same login name.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels My error, it is indeed the same username. Those generic usernames get me every time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would be better suited as a comment or not but:

- Line 33: You don't have a variable named 'richterLabel'. Check the
  spelling on the JLabel you've declared near the top.
- Line 45: You haven't declared 'label'. Did you mean to refer to
  earthLabel instead?
- Lines 59-64: You haven't declared your panel variable.

Edit: Formatting.